# How do you determine what executable and DLL’s a C# Visual Studio project produces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2010, executable

How do you determine what executable and DLL’s a C# Visual Studio project produces?

In Visual Studio 2010, where do you go to see what the name of the executable that a project produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C# project will produce just one assembly output (DLL or EXE).  Additional assemblies will be included from references that are not installed in the GAC.  For instance, if you add a reference to another project in the solution, it will copy that project's output assembly to the current project's bin folder.

Check the bin folder after build to see what was generated and included.  e.g. `<project folder>/bin/Debug`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the `<AssemblyName>` section in the .csproj file. Combined with the `<OutputType>` section to determine the file extension.

Comment: Additionally to find it through the GUI right click on the project, click properties and navigate to the application tab.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0c12ze9.aspx

Comment: Yep, looking at the question again, that's probably what is asked for, been thinking too much about file parsing lately...